# Primary key column(s) (id) are not columns in this table ()

Tags: zend-framework, primary-key, wamp

I am following the: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html.

Keep hitting wall after wall of issues. My current one is the following error:

```
    An error occurred

Application error

Exception information:

Message: Primary key column(s) (id) are not columns in this table ()

Stack trace:

#0 C:\wamp\www\zendtest\quickstart\library\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php(982): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_setupPrimaryKey()
#1 C:\wamp\www\zendtest\quickstart\library\Zend\Db\Table\Select.php(100): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->info()
#2 C:\wamp\www\zendtest\quickstart\library\Zend\Db\Table\Select.php(78): Zend_Db_Table_Select->setTable(Object(Application_Model_DbTable_Guestbook))
#3 C:\wamp\www\zendtest\quickstart\library\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php(1018): Zend_Db_Table_Select->__construct(Object(Application_Model_DbTable_Guestbook))
#4 C:\wamp\www\zendtest\quickstart\library\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php(1326): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->select()
#5 C:\wamp\www\zendtest\quickstart\application\models\GuestbookMapper.php(58): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->fetchAll()
#6 C:\wamp\www\zendtest\quickstart\application\controllers\GuestbookController.php(14): Application_Model_GuestbookMapper->fetchAll()
#7 C:\wamp\www\zendtest\quickstart\library\Zend\Controller\Action.php(516): GuestbookController->indexAction()
#8 C:\wamp\www\zendtest\quickstart\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('indexAction')
#9 C:\wamp\www\zendtest\quickstart\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#10 C:\wamp\www\zendtest\quickstart\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#11 C:\wamp\www\zendtest\quickstart\library\Zend\Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#12 C:\wamp\www\zendtest\quickstart\public\index.php(26): Zend_Application->run()
#13 {main}  
Request Parameters:

array (
  'controller' => 'guestbook',
  'action' => 'index',
  'module' => 'default',
)
```

But I am sure my table has a primary key id for table:

```
CREATE TABLE guestbook (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    email VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'noemail@test.com',
    comment TEXT NULL,
    created DATETIME NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX "id" ON "guestbook" ("id");
```

Don't understand why getting error.

How can I see if it is even picking up the right database

Comment: Check for trailing spaces after the column names, and please post the output of the query `SHOW CREATE TABLE guestbook` so we can double check the actual structure

Comment: how can a display the out put with cmd promt

Comment: we meet again! :) ... Since you are using wamp, you must have phpmyadmin installed on your system. Go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin , there you can see all databases on left side, click on your database. Then, there will be a tab called SQL, u can put @TimFountain 's command there and show us what the output was... Also, make sure you have some data inside the tables :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` contains a protected property called `_primary` which defaults to `id`.

It assumes that `id` is the table's primary key and is a sequence (auto increment).

Since your table definition says that `id` is a primary key, you should get rid of the second SQL command that adds an index on the `id` column.  Since its already a primary key, it is an index.

Delete the table and re-create it using the create table statement you have in your question, just don't do the `CREATE INDEX` part.  After that you should be able to continue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your SQL schema is incorrect. Try to create table with primary kyy like this:

```
CREATE TABLE guestbook (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'noemail@test.com',
    comment TEXT NULL,
    created DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: So been looking in to it more and it seems it didnt even create the database even though it said it did. thinking of reinstalling wamp and starting again

Answer (score 0):

This error might be induced by (accidentally) using **md5(null)** as the cache ID. Or any other customary values, for that matter, e.g. 1, 0, true, false. However, null is very likely to be the culprit in this context, as it could be produced by an undefined variable.

A fix could be as simple as:

```
    $cache = Zend_Registry::get('cache');
    $cache->remove(md5(null));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem was that database was created in guestbook-dev.db instead of guestbook.db. You can check it by looking into this files. The solution was to change scripts/load.sqlite.php from
    `defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (null === $env) ? 'development' : $env);`
to: 
    `defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (null === $env) ? 'production' : $env);`
and, of course, running the script once again.